# Send message when external API call is successful in Bot Framework

Tags: rest, azure, api, botframework, chatbot

I am making an external post REST API call from Bot Framework. If the status of the call is 200(OK), then I need to send an "API Request Success" else "API Request Failed."

Example code:

Xyz.js

```js
module.exports.Xyz = function Xyz(params) {

   request.get(`url`,
     function (error, response, body) {


       if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
        //
         return await step.context.sendActivity(`API Request Failed`);
        }
       var jobSubmitted = JSON.parse(response.body);

         return await step.context.sendActivity(`API Request Success`);
      }); 

}

index.js i have below function

  async sendMessage(step){

         Xyz.Xyz();

         return await step.endDialog();
     }
```

Currently I am getting an error "await is only valid in async function".

Actual Expectation
1) The bot should wait for the REST service response and then it should send the message.

I am completely new to Node JS and the Bot Framework. I am looking for a good approach to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As per the above error, you can't use the await statement inside a function that isn't declared as async. So if this code is inside a function, make that function async.

Correct Implementation :

```
module.exports.Xyz =  function Xyz(params) {

   request.get(`url`,
   async function (error, response, body) {


       if (response.statusCode !== 200) {

         return await step.context.sendActivity(`API Request Failed`);
        }
       var jobSubmitted = JSON.parse(response.body);

         return await step.context.sendActivity(`API Request Success`);
      }); 

}



  async function sendMessage(step){

         Xyz.Xyz();

         return await step.endDialog();
     }
```

You can get a better idea on async functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).